# Application Keeps Crashing (Camera)

Tags: android

Im making an application where you take a photo and it displays it as well as changing what the background image looks like. My application keeps crashing and was wondering if you guys know whats the issue. Cheers

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // label our logs "CameraApp3"
    private static String logtag = "CameraApp3";
    // tells us which camera to take a picture from
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    // empty variable to hold our image Uri once we store it
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // look for the button we set in the view
        Button cameraButton = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
        // set a listener on the button
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);


    }

    // set a new listener
    private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open the camera and pass in the current view
            takePhoto(v);
        }
    };

    public void takePhoto(View v) {
        // tell the phone we want to use the camera
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        // create a new temp file called pic.jpg in the "pictures" storage area of the phone
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "pic.jpg");
        // take the return data and store it in the temp file "pic.jpg"
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        // stor the temp photo uri so we can find it later
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        // start the camera
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // override the original activity result function
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // call the parent
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        // if the requestCode was equal to our camera code (1) then...
        case 1:
            // if the user took a photo and selected the photo to use
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the image uri from earlier
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                // notify any apps of any changes we make
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                // get the imageView we set in our view earlier
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
                // create a content resolver object which will allow us to access the image file at the uri above
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                // create an empty bitmap object
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    // get the bitmap from the image uri using the content resolver api to get the image
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // set the bitmap to the image view
                    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MyAndroidAppActivity:

```
package com.example.triptych4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);


            }


        });

    }



}
```

Layout

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="258dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-352dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/middle" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-167dp"
                android:text="Change Image" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
05-06 14:41:19.363: I/art(1335): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1722(89KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 1.335ms total 105.604ms
05-06 14:41:19.650: D/AndroidRuntime(1335): Shutting down VM
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): Process: com.example.triptych4, PID: 1335
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.triptych4/com.example.triptych4.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.example.triptych4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-06 14:41:19.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     ... 10 more
05-06 14:41:55.802: I/Process(1335): Sending signal. PID: 1335 SIG: 9
05-06 14:42:21.608: I/art(1378): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 117(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 11.483ms total 365.174ms
05-06 14:42:22.181: D/AndroidRuntime(1378): Shutting down VM
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Process: com.example.triptych4, PID: 1378
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.triptych4/com.example.triptych4.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.example.triptych4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-06 14:42:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     ... 10 more
05-06 14:47:24.069: I/Process(1378): Sending signal. PID: 1378 SIG: 9
05-06 14:50:00.607: I/art(1428): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1722(89KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 1.353ms total 189.333ms
05-06 14:50:00.742: D/AndroidRuntime(1428): Shutting down VM
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Process: com.example.triptych4, PID: 1428
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.triptych4/com.example.triptych4.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.example.triptych4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-06 14:50:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     ... 10 more
05-06 14:50:08.090: I/Process(1428): Sending signal. PID: 1428 SIG: 9
05-06 14:50:31.291: I/art(1467): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 61.291ms total 133.616ms
05-06 14:50:31.352: D/AndroidRuntime(1467): Shutting down VM
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): Process: com.example.triptych4, PID: 1467
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.triptych4/com.example.triptych4.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.example.triptych4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-06 14:50:31.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)`

Comment: You are try to cast ImageButton as Button so replace this code :  ImageButtoncameraButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are try to cast ImageButton as Button so replace this code :

```
ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
```

Comment: @Harrison,If you problem is resolve now then you can accept any one ans who given first solution or hint to resolve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xml you have `ImageButton`.

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_camera"
    .... />
```

But in your MainActivity you are using it as `Button`.

```
Button cameraButton = (Button)
            findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
```

Change it to `ImageButton`.

```
ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)
            findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `ImageButton`cameraButton into `Button` .

use

```
ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
```

instead of

```
Button cameraButton = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
```